How to draw a coloured Bloch sphere in Latex using Tikz package?
I want to draw the Bloch sphere in Latex using the Tikz package. There are some tutorials on how to create a basic Bloch sphere but I want to add more details to it. For example, I would like to get a colored Bloch sphere like this one (Source: https://gnulinux.ch/quantencomputer-teil-2-die-logik)

Do you have any idea on how to implement this kind of Bloch sphere in Latex?
Thanks in advance!

Maybe have a look at the blochsphere package.
